# i phone 4s as a gift 3rd party owner

Tags: iphone

I received a second hand I phone 4s as a gift it has not been reported stolen or lost. being the 3 party owner how can I delete the account attached to this phone to activate it

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings / General / Reset / Reset All Content and Settings.
This will wipe the device and restore it to a factory-settings state.

If you do this, nothing will be left on the device (data, settings, accounts, etc) and you'll have a fresh start with the phone.

Answer (score 0):

If the iPhone is running iOS 7 and in iCloud settings is "Find my iPhone" activated, you will need the old owners iCloud password to disable Activation-Lock, as you can't delete all data while Activation-Lock is activated.
If Activation-Lock is disabled, simply go to `Settings -> General -> Reset -> Erase All Content And Settings`.